# How to save file objects to the database? - Python(Flask)

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to add an attachment field to my project where user can upload different type of files and each ticket would have its files attached to it and here is my code

```
class Files(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
        description = db.Column(db.String(140),nullable=False)
        file = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
        timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
        author = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
        ticket_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tickets.id'),nullable=False)

class AddFile(FlaskForm):
       description = StringField('Description',validators=[DataRequired()])
       file = FileField('Files',validators=[FileRequired()])
       submit = SubmitField('Upload')

@app.route('/ticket/<ticket_id>',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def ticket(ticket_id):
        if fileform.validate_on_submit() and fileform.file.data:
            newFile = Files(description=fileform.description.data,file=fileform.file.data.read(),author = current_user.username)
            db.session.add(newFile)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Your file has been uploaded.')
            return redirect(url_for('ticket', ticket_id=ticket_id))
        return render_template('ticket.html',ticket=ticket,fileform=fileform,filemodel=filemodel)
```

when I upload it I don't get any error however when I open the database and check my `Files` column, the `file` is emtpy. I believe I need to somehow convert `file = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)` to the regular field so I can store it on database

Comment: Does this actually return anything?   `fileform.file.data.read()`

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you get in form from browser. Sometimes problem can be that if you `read()` data from file then it gets all data from file and using again `read()` will get nothing. And then it is good to `read()` only once and asign to variable and later use values in this variable instead of second `read()`.